# how to write a startup dependency on Internet availability?

Tags: debian, networking, startup, raspberry-pi

Some of the services on my Raspberry Pi (~ Debian) depend on the availability of Internet (especially `ntpd`, [for cryptic reasons](https://serverfault.com/questions/559666/why-doesnt-ntp-recover-after-an-internet-less-startup)). Specifically, the availability of a network device or a link being up is not enough.

When looking at `/etc/init.d/ntp` I see

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:        ntp
# Required-Start:  $network $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:   $network $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:   2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: Start NTP daemon
### END INIT INFO
```

which I believe means that `ntp` depends on `$network` to be able to start. I found a reference in `/etc/insserv.conf` but it does not say much about what is actually required to set it up:

```
#
# Low level networking (ethernet card)
#
$network        +networking +ifupdown
```

**Q1:** How exactly is `$network` defined via the `+networking +ifupdown` elements? (so that I can modify it and try to reach an actual host before declaring the network as 'up')

**Q2:** If the network prerequisite is not met will the `ntp` start be delayed or will it fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where is $network defined?

This is a good question, and [I've generalized it here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123877/what-provides-lsb-virtual-boot-facilities-for-debian).

> How exactly is $network defined via the +networking +ifupdown elements?

AFAICT it isn't defined by that, it defines what services must (optionally) also declare any dependencies the facility has (?? -- see the question I posted and linked above).  From `man insserv`:

> insserv scans for System Facilities in the configuration file
>   /etc/insserv.conf [...] All names  followed  by  such  a system 
>   facility  will  declare  the  required  dependencies of the facility.
>   [...] Names starting with a `+' sign are marked as optional.

And in fact on raspbian `/etc/init.d/networking` (which is started through `/etc/rcS.d`, which runs at boot regardless of runlevel) does *not* include `$network` as a prereq, although some other services (such as `ntp`) do.

> Q2: If the network prerequisite is not met will the ntp start be delayed or will it fail?

Those prereqs (and other stuff in the INIT INFO block) are only used to set up and configure the script links in the `/etc/rcN.d` directories, e.g., when you run `update-rc.d` (which is a front end for `insserv`).  In other words, they aren't used during the actual execution.  So, if `S02ntp` is in your default runlevel, it will be run *no matter what* during boot (excepting some previous fatal error).

Comment: Thank you - the last part is particularly useful. I was not aware that this information is used only when planting the script and not during actual execution. I will write a brand new question then (about how to delay a startup script).