# What provides LSB virtual boot facilities for Debian?

Tags: debian, sysvinit, lsb

Debian's version of Sysv init uses scripts which reference various [LSB "virtual" boot facilities](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_3.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/facilname.html) such as `$local_fs` and `$network` as requirements for use by insserv in setting up the boot sequence, but they are not necessarily provided by any `/etc/init.d` script.  `/etc/insserv.conf` refers to them to, but only to define what services must "declare  the  required  dependencies of the facility".  To me, this would mean that the list of services "must declare the dependencies *of* the facility", but perhaps it is just a poor choice of words, since looking at an actual `insserv.conf` implies that it actually means this list "must declare the facility *as* a dependency", which is very different (any clarification of that would be appreciated).

It is obvious that things such as `$network` (which seems to refer simply to the possibility of a physical link, i.e., not an actual dhcp lease, etc.) and `$local_fs` would be provided by the kernel during boot, but I cannot find any documentation which explains how they would be considered pre-defined as available or not available by the init system.

Answer (score 0):

With `insserv` virtual boot facilities allow init scripts to depend on widely used functionnalities provided by groups of differents scripts or by various methods accross distributions.

Depending on the `$network` target means that a configured network connection is needed. In Debian it means running the `networking` and `ifupdown` initscripts, as described in `insserv.conf`.

`$local_fs` is used for almost every startup script as it means that every local filesystems will be mounted, `$remote_fs` is obviously dependant of `$network`.

The scripts needed to reach this goals are not named the same on every distribution and can change from one OS version to another. As `insserv` can be configured differently to reflect this changes the initscripts depending on this facilities dont need to be changed for each particular case.

The idea at the time of the design of this standart by the LSB was to make init scripts less distribution dependant, something which is now provided by `systemd` in most distributions.